# Wordpress Permalink Settings optional settings doesnt apply to editor

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, categories

In my WordPress 3.8 in my "Permalink Settings" I've chosen the option "Post name". Then I've added "Optional" for "Category" ( `%category%/%postname%` ), the urls works like I wanted - `http://mywordpress.com/categoryname/postname` - however this rule doesnt apply to the editor - when I create new post or edit the existing post the url in editor is still `http://mywordpress.com/postname` so when I click on *View Post* or *Preview Changes* it redirects me to the wrong URL which shows Page Not Found....

Any help/ideas? what am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

This question was answered on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129510/permalink-settings-optional-settings-doesnt-apply-to-editor/129514

Comment: Might be other plugin is changing it. you can try removing on hook on `post_link` by `remove_all_filters('post_link')` . Also from General Settings -> Writing Settings page, chose a Default Post Category

Comment: @Shazzad Its a pure WP instalation, default post category is set too.